# How to select or view only the top row in airtable?

Tags: dataframe, airtable

I have this table:

```
    Name   | Weight | Color
1   Cherry | 1      | Red
2   Apple  | 4      | Green
3   Pear   | 3      | Yellow
```

I need a view in which only the top row is visible

```
Cherry | 1 | Red
```

When the table changes (new record, sorting), the view changes accordingly

Example 1:

```
    Name   | Weight V| Color
1   Apple  | 4       | Green
2   Pear   | 3       | Yellow
3   Cherry | 1       | Red
```

single row view:

```
Apple | 4 | Green
```

Example 2:

```
    Name   | Weight  | Color
1   Almond | 0.5     | Brown
2   Apple  | 4       | Green
3   Pear   | 3       | Yellow
4   Cherry | 1       | Red
```

single row view:

```
Almond | 0.5 | Brown
```

This doesn't seem possible. Didn't find anything in related forums.

GPT3 suggestions were selecting a record by `row_id` or `time_of_creation` fields, but this won't help with table resorting.

It also suggested using `SELECT(table_name, {}, {limit: N, fields: ["field_1", "field_2"]})` - but `limit` does not work. Same for `FIRST()` which doesn't exist.

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Try a [record list](https://support.airtable.com/docs/record-list-extension). You can sort elements there as well as limit how many you want to list.

I guess the other would be scripting and just "limiting" what the query returns when displaying it (which doesn't sound like what you want). I am not sure there is a simple native way.

I guess in the end record list limits are the closest to what you are trying to achieve, especially since your main criterion for a top row is sorting.